# Visual Studio 2012 Add controller with Context fails when connectionstring configSource in place

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, frameworks, entity, configsource

Working with VS 2012 + MVC4 + EF5 trying to add controller with Context fails when connectionstring configSource in place with Error :

"Unable to retrieve metadata for MvcTestApp.Models.DummyClass. Unable to open configSource file 'connections.config'.

BTW: The path is correct the application actually runs correctly.

Does Visual Studio 2012 EF5 support connectionStrings configSource to be in a separated file at design time ? or no way during development !!!

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. I solved it putting a copy of 'connections.config' in

```
C:\Users\[CurrentUser]\AppData\Local\Temp.
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: +1, but I don't know if I should be sad or happy that this is the solution. How much does Visual Studio cost? yet it can't even find the configSource defined in the config. Tut tut.

Comment: @NeilThompson Thank you for your point. I searched for a solution of the "problem" just because... In fact, I think that during development there are no reason for this approach - external configSource.